# Numpy- How to create ROI iteratively in OpenCV python?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am trying to split an image in a grid of smaller images so that I can process each small image separately. For that I realized that I'll have to define each small image as an ROI and I can use it easily from there.

Now, my grid size is not fixed. I.e, if user inputs 5, I have to make a grid of 5x5.

Iterating over the image pixel by pixel would be slow, so I decided to use Numpy to create ROI by using this construct :

```
#Assuming user entered grid size =5
roiwidth=w/5
roiheight=h/5   
roi0=img[0:roiheight,0:roiwidth]
```

This would be my first slice. h and w are height and width of the image respectively. For the next slice I'd have to do:

```
roi1=img[0:roiheight,roiwidth+1:2*roiwidth]
```

While my last roi will be:

```
roi25=img[4*roiheight+1:5*roiheight, 4*roiwidth+1:5*roiwidth]
```

But I need to do it iteratively, and cannot figure out the correct way to do that. I don't want to iterate over the image pixel by pixel and need it to be dynamic

**EDIT**: I am iterating like this now:

```
import cv2
import numpy

img=cv2.imread('01.jpg')
h,w,chan=img.shape
rh=h/5
rw=w/5
z={}
count=0
for i in range (0,5):
    for j in range (0,5):
        yl=i*rh
        yh=(i+1)*rh
        xl=j*rw
        xh=(j+1)*rw
        z[count]=img[yl:yh,xl:xh]
        count=count+1
```

But I don't know whether this is the most efficient way of doing this.

Comment: What is your problem exactly ? Just efficiency ?

Comment: Yes, currently I'm still using python loops, which are slow. If I could somehow use just numpy (which is in C and is considerably faster), then my script will be much more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For efficiency purposes, listed below is a vectorized approach using reshaping and permuting dimensions.

1) Let's define the input parameters and setup inputs :

```
M = 5 # Number of patches along height and width
img_slice = img[:rh*M,:rw*M] # Slice out valid image data
```

2) The main processing part comes here. Split the first two axes of sliced image such that we create two new axes of lengths `M` each by reshaping. Thus, the two remaining axes would represent the window `(rh x rw)`. Our final aim is to bring them adjacent to each other so as to give us `(rh,rw)` patches and thus the other two split axes would also come next to each other. To do so, we need to permute dimensions with `np.transpose`. After permuting, we reshape to merge the two dimensions of lengths `(M,M)` so that we end up with one axis of length `M^2`, each of whose element would represent one window from the image.

So, finally we would have :

```
z = img_slice.reshape(M,rh,M,rw,-1).transpose(0,2,1,3,4).reshape(M**2,rh,rw,-1)
```

This gives us a NumPy array with `M^2` elements along the first axis. Each slice along that axis would correspond to each window/patch. So, `z[0]` would be the top left corner patch and so on.

Comment: Could you explain in a little detail what that code is doing? I tried running it and got the error : `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
`

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to split your image using Numpy functions, take a look at [numpy.array_split](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html).

In your case you would write something like this:

```
z = {}
count = 0
split1 = np.array_split(img, rh)
for sub in split1:
    split2 = np.array_split(sub, rw, 1)
    for sub2 in split2:
        z[count] = sub2
        count++
```

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the most efficient way. I'll run some tests and find out whether there is a significant difference between my method and this one.

Comment: @ChaoticTwist  Actually, you probably have to transpose the subarrays after the first split. I changed the code to reflect that

Comment: No need for that, `np.array_split` takes a third parameter, which specifies axis along which the array has to be split (default is 0). Therefore if I put 1 in the `split2` I get the output I expect.

Comment: Alternatively, `numpy.hsplit` (column wise split) and `numpy.vsplit` (row wise split) functions can also be used.